# Which service account to use for Kerberos in out-of-the-box SharePoint?

Tags: kerberos, service-account

I just installed SharePoint2013 Enterprise on Windows 7.

Now trying to set up Kerberos authentication, following [this guide](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/09/26/the-first-kerberos-guide-for-sharepoint-2013-technicians/).

PROBLEM: What is "serviceaccount"? In this context:

> 2.2 Next, list all SPN already in Place for the Service Account, type: setSPN -L domain\serviceaccount

AD only has the following accounts: Administrator, Guest HVU_MYMACHINE, krbtgt
Should I enter one of them?

*It is only for testing a client software, so account compromission is not a worry, if that matters.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the account running the application pool.

If you look at the guide you linked to, he adds: `corp\spwebapp`

Comment: The guide also says that it should work without the domain name, so I just typed `setspn -L spwebapp` (literally), but that results in a error saying that `spwebapp` is not recognized.

Comment: Yes, that's because you probably don't have a domain called corp or a user named spwebapp. Easy to check from IIS Manager -> Application Pools, and look at the identity running the pool for your site. That's the user you are looking for